# Content Resolver query returns empty cursor only on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Lollipop

Tags: android

I have this code and I've tested it on a few devices, works on them, except for a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Lollipop. The `getContentResolver().query()` method returns an empty cursor, every time. If the if/else statement goes to the else, because of that, and tries `insert` I get another null as the result of the `insert`

```
        String mediaTitle = String.format("My Artist%s", title);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, mediaTitle);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "My Artist");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
        String selection = String.format("%s = ?", MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE);
        c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, new String[]{mediaTitle}, null); // RETURNS NULL only on Samsung Galaxy S4 with Lollipop

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            return uri.buildUpon().appendPath(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)))).build();
        } else {
            return getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `insert` method won't insert the ringtone if it isn't unique and I wasn't able to query for that `Uri` properly so I was trying to insert something that was already there.

I should have either fixed the way I query for it, which is strange, because on other devices it worked, or do this:

```
 getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
```

before the `query`, which deletes the files that are already there, and allowed me to `insert` them anew and now the `insert` doesn't return null anymore. A bit of a brute force solution, but it helped me.

Comment: You should probably use `getContentResolver().update( ...` instead